# Is strictly harmonic 2D lattice made of Hooke springs possible?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring, linear-systems

If we connect a set of point masses in a 1D lattice with Hooke springs and consider longitudinal oscillations, we'll have a strictly harmonic system, for which there exist eigenmodes and the frequency of oscillations doesn't depend on amplitude. If we choose transverse oscillations, they cease to be harmonic: the potential for small oscillations appears to be $\sim \Delta x^4$.

Now I'd like to generalize the first case, where the oscillations are linear, to 2 dimensions. However, it appears that if we make, e.g. a rectangular lattice with nearest neighbours connected by Hooke springs, then any displacement of a lattice site leads to longitudinal deformation of two springs *and* transverse deformation of two others, thus making the returning force nonlinear function of displacement. Arranging the masses into a triangular lattice doesn't help to compensate the nonlinearity.

So, the question is: is it possible to make a *strictly harmonic* 2D lattice using just point masses connected by Hooke springs? What would be an example of such an arrangement?

Comment: If all the springs have the same spring constant then the longitudinal forces will be of a much higher order than the transverse forces, such that the non-linearity might be neglected.

Comment: @fibonatic this is why I emphasized _strictly_. I'm interested in an exact model, not approximate one. Otherwise I could use tensioned springs and that would be enough.

Comment: @Ruslan: I'm not aware of a mathematically rigorous proof of impossibility of a truly harmonic arrangement in 2D, but I highly doubt it is possible. At large vibration amplitudes, the lattice itself will be distorted by the vibrations, altering the potential surface in what will almost certainly be a nonlinear fashion, seeing as the angles between the point masses will be changing. Large amplitude deformations typically kills any chance of eigenmode analysis, so if small amplitude oscillation is not acceptable then you may be out of luck.

Comment: @Ruslan: In the event of small amplitude oscillation, the quartic contribution is negligible, and the $N\times N$ rectangular lattice with fixed outer boundaries actually can be decomposed into $2N$ copies of the 1-dimensional system of length $N$, which is exactly solvable since the Hessian of the potential is a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix, whose eigendecomposition is well-known. I can post it as an answer, along with an example of what happens when you use a hexagonal lattice with fixed outer boundaries, but it's only valid at small amplitude.

Comment: @Ruslan: Just curious, what are you trying to model in 2D for which you're trying to find a strictly harmonic lattice?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus that's just theoretical interest, to understand these things better.